# How to show results line by line? in C

Tags: c++

When my program executes it shows all 'cout(s)' in one line, like this,

[image: all couts in one line]

while I want it to show them line by line to make my program nice! I want it to show them like this:

```
Circumference of the circle: (This)
Diameter of the circle: (This)
Area of the circle: (This)
```

Comment: I can't believe that the example programs in whatever textbook or website you're learning from don't show how to do this. Come on, this must be a joke.

Comment: For future questions, note that here at SO, if you have problem with code, you should usually show the code... usually in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `endl` or `\n` :

```
cout<<"Circumference of the circle:"<<your_value<<endl;
```

or

```
cout<<"Circumference of the circle:"<<your_value<<"\n";
```

Comment: @AhmedRaza Dont forget to mark correct answers, not just for this, for any question :-)

Comment: Actually this is my first experience on this site, so i'm totally blank yet, i mean i don't know most of the things about this site. I was looking for answer on google and it threw me here :D

Answer (score 0):

Simply print a newline character (written with `\n`) where you want a line break. In C:

```
printf("The value: %d\n", value);
```

Or in C++:

```
cout << "The value: " << value << "\n";
```